# CKEditor with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I have a problem, I can't use CKEditor with Angular

```
<div ng-repeat="item in site.SiteLanguages" id='{{"Tab_Add_" +item.Abbreviation}}' ng-class="{active:$first}" class="tab-pane fade in" style="min-height: 310px;">
    <textarea ng-model="item.PageContent" name='{{"pagecontent" +item.abbreviation}}'></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('{{"pagecontent" + item.abbreviation}}');
    </script>
</div>
```

The problem: I can't pass textarea name to js script

```
CKEDITOR.replace('{{"pagecontent" + item.abbreviation}}');
```

How can I replace with textarea name?

Comment: You can look at CKEditor directive for Angular.